# Catching HTTP response event

Tags: node.js, events, express, httpresponse

I am building a Node web application (using Express) and to keep everything as DRY as possible, I automatically acquire database connection for each request but I also need to release it (back to the pool).

I could do that manually in every route but that would be just polluting the code. I figured that I should listen to server events and release it once response is either finished generating or sending. What options do I have? What events (and inside which object (app, request or whatever) are triggered when response is complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`res` is inherited from EventEmitter, and can use default events as well as you can emit own ones.
So one of the most common would be `finish` (in node.0.8.12 and older `end`) event:

```
res.on('finish', function() {
  // request processing finished
});
```

You can attach that event for all requests if you want, or to specific early in their roots.
Additionally you can create middleware, that would get DB connection, and attach `finish` event and possibly timeouts. And then all you will need is to add that middleware into routes, so minimum of repetitive coding.

In mean time, I would recommend you not to create DB connection for each request, as it is a big overhead and unnecessary use of sockets as well as IO handlers. You can freely use onse single connection, and it will be as efficient from performance point of view.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it might not be required to create a DB connection for each request. This is something different from other server environments mainly because Node.js uses a single thread.

Comment: Single thread + you can simply access variables and stuff outside of request scope. You can have array of even shared data, or anything similar. While e.g. in PHP, every thread - is fully isolated from each other - sux.

Comment: @Plato, me too. I looked for events available in Node documentation but the only one I found for `HttpResponse` was `close` event (which is not exactly what I wanted).

P.S. I wasn't going to create new connection for each request, just pick one from the pool. I just really dislike the idea of repeating connection acquirement code in every route.

Comment: @MaksimsMihejevs, I digged deeper into this `end` event and it turned out that since Node 0.8.12, that event is renamed to `finish`. Please add this to your comment so that people wouldn't get confused. :)